# Get a working mod_rewrite and .htaccess on custom php site

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I just need that this URL `www.mysite.com/index.php?url=othersite.com` gets rewritten to `www.mysite.com/othersite.com`

I have written this `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ index.php?url=$1
```

Also added that code to a `.htaccess` file and uploaded to site root together with `index.php` file, but no matter what, I always get `www.mysite.com/index.php?url=othersite.com`

Thanks a lot in advise!

Comment: what do you mean `I always get ..`

Comment: Hi, I mean,  that posting this "/index.php?url=othersite.com" from a form to index.php, I dont get the friendly URL that I want /othersite.com

Comment: Where do you *get* `www.mysite.com/index.php?url=othersite.com` from? Do you type that in the address bar? Does it come from an internal link? Does it get generated by a page?

Comment: those friendly URLs are generated by php (or something like that) and mod-rewrite is used to send them to php!

Comment: Hi, I have a form <form method="get" name="downform" action="" onsubmit="return formSubmit()"> that get submitted by a JS function "        function formSubmit() {
          domain = document.getElementById('domain_input').value;
          window.location = '/' + domain;
          return false;
        }", I have 0 experience in this so in PHP I just want to see ig the vars are passed <?php var_dump($_GET);> but I receive a 404 not found error on submitting the form

Answer (score 0):

Well, solved it this way.
Form

```
<form method="post" name="downform" action="" onsubmit="return formSubmit()">
```

JS

```
function formSubmit() {
  domain = document.getElementById('domain_input').value;
  window.location = '/' + domain;
  return false;
}
```

.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)$ index.php?domain=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+)/$ index.php?domain=$1

<files .htaccess>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</files>
```

PHP (Just to see the result)

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']!='/')
    echo trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');
```